# Whenever I upload the image the chart works but whenever I upload a new image the chart bars height is not changed while the value changes

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html\>

    Vivo Object Detection

     <h1>Upload your file here </h1>

      <!--File: -->
      
    
    
    
    
    <!-- Image will be displayed here -->
    
    
    
     <p><b></b></p>
     <p></p>

      <!-- Chart start -->

    <ul>
      <li>100%</li>
      <li>50%</li>
      <li>0%</li>
      </ul>
       <ul>
      <li>Vivo</li>
      <li>Samsung</li>
      <li>Oppo</li>
      <li>Xiaomi</li>
       </ul>

      <!-- Chart end -->

        function uploadImage(event) {
         const file = event.target.files\[0\];
          const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
    
         axios.post("https://detect.roboflow.com/vivo/5?api_key=ZctjutykcfT7GHP3fx5L", formData)
        .then(function (response) {
          const json = response.data;
          const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
          // The rest of the code for processing the response and chart animation
        let VivoCount = 0;
         let OppoCount = 0;
         let MI_Count = 0;
          let Samsung_Count = 0;
    
            let Vivo_Total_Confidence = 0;
    
         let Oppo_Total_Confidence = 0;
    
         let Mi_Total_Confidence = 0;
    
        let samsung_Total_Confidence = 0;
    
       obj.predictions.forEach(element =\> {
         if(element.class == "Vivo"){
    
          if(obj.predictions\[VivoCount\].confidence == "NAN%")
          {
              Vivo_Total_Confidence = 0;
              
          }
          else{
    
            Vivo_Total_Confidence += obj.predictions\[VivoCount\].confidence;
            //console.log(Total_Confidence);
            VivoCount ++;
          }
            
        }
        
        if(element.class == "Samsung"){
            
          if(obj.predictions\[Samsung_Count\].confidence == "NAN%")
          {
              samsung_Total_Confidence = 0;
              
          }
          else{
    
            samsung_Total_Confidence += obj.predictions\[Samsung_Count\].confidence;
            //console.log(Total_Confidence);
            Samsung_Count ++;
          }
        }
        
        if(element.class == "Oppo"){
    
          if(obj.predictions\[OppoCount\].confidence == "NAN%")
          {
              Oppo_Total_Confidence = 0;
              
          }
            Oppo_Total_Confidence += obj.predictions\[OppoCount\].confidence;
            //console.log(Total_Confidence);
            OppoCount ++;
        }
    
        if(element.class == "Xiaomi"){
    
          if(obj.predictions\[MI_Count\].confidence == "NAN%")
          {
              Mi_Total_Confidence = 0;
              
          }
            Mi_Total_Confidence += obj.predictions\[MI_Count\].confidence;
            //console.log(Total_Confidence);
            MI_Count ++;
        }
       });
    
        if(VivoCount == 0){
         }
    
        let Vivo_average = Vivo_Total_Confidence / VivoCount;
     
        let Mi_average = Mi_Total_Confidence / MI_Count;
    
         let Oppo_average = Oppo_Total_Confidence / OppoCount;
    
        let Samsung_average = samsung_Total_Confidence / Samsung_Count;
    
    
        let Vivo_Cal_confidence = Vivo_average\* 100;
         let Mi_Cal_confidence = Mi_average\* 100;
         let Samsung_Cal_confidence = Samsung_average\* 100;
         let Oppo_Cal_confidence = Oppo_average\* 100;
         //console.log(Cal_confidence);
    
    
    
    
          var Vivo_conf = Math.floor(Vivo_Cal_confidence);
         var Mi_conf = Math.floor(Mi_Cal_confidence);
         var Oppo_conf = Math.floor(Oppo_Cal_confidence);
          var Samsung_conf = Math.floor(Samsung_Cal_confidence);
    
       console.log(Vivo_conf + " %" + " Vivo");
       console.log(Mi_conf + " %" + " MI");
       console.log(Samsung_conf + " %" + " Samsung");
       console.log(Oppo_conf + " %" + " Oppo");
    
      document.querySelector('.bars li:nth-child(1) .bar').setAttribute('data-percentage',   Vivo_conf);

       document.querySelector('.bars li:nth-child(2) .bar').setAttribute('data-percentage', Samsung_conf);
      document.querySelector('.bars li:nth-child(3) .bar').setAttribute('data-percentage', Oppo_conf);
       document.querySelector('.bars li:nth-child(4) .bar').setAttribute('data-percentage', Mi_conf);
      $(function () {
      $('.bars li .bar').each(function (key, bar) {
       var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');
       $(this).animate({
      'height': percentage + '%'
       }, 1000);
      });
       });

          // // Display the percentages in the respective elements
          // document.getElementById('vivo_result'). = Vivo_conf;
          // document.getElementById('oppo').innerHTML = Oppo_conf;
          // document.getElementById('samsung').innerHTML = Samsung_conf;
          // document.getElementById('xiaomi').innerHTML = Mi_conf;
    
    
    
          document.getElementById('myChart').style.display="block";

         document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML ="Confidence in detecting VIVO is: " +     Vivo_conf + "%";

          document.getElementById('vivocount').innerHTML =
                      "Detection Frequency: " + VivoCount + " times";

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
    
       // Display the uploaded image
         const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');
        imageContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear any previous image
        const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
        imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
         imgElement.style.maxWidth = '100%';
        imageContainer.appendChild(imgElement);
       }
    
    
      
       $(function () {
         $('.bars li .bar').each(function (key, bar) {
          var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');
           $(this).animate({
             'height': percentage + '%'
           }, 1000);
       });
```

The chart should change the bars height whenever the values of the variables are changed.  **The chart is not updating its height whenever I upload a new image.**
I upload an image in the website at first it works properly and the chart works but when I upload the second image the chart values do change but the height of the bar remains the same. I need to change those.